# Editing and adding the sum of java arrys

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to iterate over an array and add the sum of the array except the number 13 and the number after it.
Example
[1,1,1,1,13,2] = [1,1,1,1,0,0] = 4

this is what I have so far the main things I need to know is how do I check if the array has a number 13 in it and how do I change it to a 0

```
   public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
       
       for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
           
           if(nums.indexOf(i) == 13) {
               
           }
            
       }
        
    }
  


    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //this is the main method
        int[] a = {1,2,3,13,4};
        
        sum13(a);
        

}
}
```

Comment: Just sum the values and break from the loop when you encounter a `13`.

Comment: Do you want to change all the values to 0 after you encounter a 13? or only the number immediately after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this , to skip adding all number when you get 13 in your array :

```
public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
           int sum = 0;
           for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
               
               if(nums[i] == 13) {
                   break;
               }
                sum += nums[i];
           }
            return sum;
        }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            //this is the main method
            int[] a = {1,2,3,13,4};
            
            System.out.println(sum13(a));
            

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static int sum13(int[] nums) {
    return IntStream.of(nums).takeWhile(i -> i != 13).sum();
}
```